# How to document standalone function with yuidoc comments

Tags: javascript, documentation

I want to generate documentation for a collection of javascript files.

I'm trying to generate with yuidoc, but I don't know how to document standalone functions.

```
function getNullString(){...}
```

Methods in classes works Ok:

```
/**
* ArgumentBuilder
*
* @class argumentBuilder
* @argumentBuilder
*/
function argumentBuilder () {
    /// &lt;summary&gt;Clase utilizada para lo relacionado con funciones del constructor de arguemtnario&lt;/summary&gt;
};

/**
* Explanation of the method
*
* @method getComponents
*/
argumentBuilder.getComponents = function (){}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It seems YUIDocs is prepared only to "read" class/module workflows. My solution was to create a fictitious class and then document the functions on it with the @method annotation.

Imagine a ini.js file, on top of it you can create a @class annotation:

```
/**
Main application init functions
@class init
*/
```

And then on the functions, use the @method annotation:

```
/**
My function description here
@method myFunctionName
*/
```

Doing this is true that an "invalid" class "init" will be created on the documentation, but at least your method will also appear documented in the docs.

Comment: I don't like this solution, but I have found no other work around. +1

Comment: I couldn't get this to work... YUIdoc still generates nothing: https://github.com/bevry/assert-helpers/blob/b9b7db5f22141f27895d8ae5a855b34eb0b23b19/esnext/lib/helpers.js